# how to make foreman port accessible from outside in mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, foreman

I have a rails application that use foreman to serve on localhost:3001.
I turned off the whole firewall but still it's not accessible from out side.
How can I share this port to the network?

Comment: Have you tried binding server to Ip address like `rails s -b 111.11.11.111` while running?

Comment: thanks that works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the development mode rails server from another computer(remote access).You need to bind the server to the ip like this:

> rails s -b 111.11.11.111       // `111.11.11.111 is an example for ip address`